# AWS Lambda to check DynamoDB KMS encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I want to write a Lambda function to catch any table in DynamoDB which is not using KMS encryption. I am planning to do the following:

1. Create a SNS topic
2. Write a Lambda function
3. Trigger the Lambda function from CloudWatch event: CreateTable

My question is: in the JSON document if KMS is not being used then the following lines will not be in the event details

```
"sSEDescription": {
                 "sSEType": "KMS",
                 "kMSMasterKeyArn": "",
                 "status": "ENABLED"
            },
```

So in my python code should I check for `sSEDescription is NULL` or is there a better way?

Appreciate any input to make my code better.

Comment: Every table is encrypted in DynamoDB.

Comment: Yes, every table is encrypted in DynamoDB by default. But for some compliance reason we wish to use KMS it shows in the CloudWatch logs with details shown above. I  have a solution by reading the event as Dict and checking for [sSEDescription]. If null / error SNS is triggered.

Comment: Are you saying more specifically that you wish to have your own key in KMS and have this script confirm it is using that key and not the default service key?

Comment: yes, compliance has demanded for reasons beyond my control.